# CodeIgniter HMVC data not passing from one function to another

Tags: php, codeigniter, hmvc

i am passing function _homepage to index but it does not pass the $data['articles'] with it.
can any one help me to solve this?
this code is updated

```
      public function index(){
    $mydata = array();
    $this->mydata['menu'] = $this->Mdl_page->get_nested();
    $this->mydata['page'] = $this->Mdl_page->get_by(array('slug' => (string) $this->uri->segment(1)), TRUE);
    count($this->mydata['page']) || show_404(current_url());

    //fetch page data
    $method = '_' . $this->mydata['page']->template;
    if (method_exists($this, $method)) {
        $this->$method();
    }
    else {
        log_message('error', 'Could not load template ' . $method .' in file ' . __FILE__ . ' at line ' . __LINE__);
        show_error('Could not load template ' . $method);
    }
    $this->mydata['subview'] = $data['page']->template;
    //dump($data);
    $this->load->view('_main_layout', $this->mydata);

}

private function _page(){
    dump('Welcome from the page template');
}
private function _homepage(){
    $this->load->model('admin/Mdl_Articles');
    $this->db->limit(6);
    $this->mydata['articles'] = $this->Mdl_Articles->get();
    //dump($data['articles']);

}
private function _news_archive(){
    dump('Welcome from the newspage template');
}
```

Comment: `$data['articles']` is in the local scope of the method `_homepage` you can not retrieve `$data` variable unless you return it `return $this->Mdl_Articles->get();` and in your index method `$data['articles'] = $this->$method();`
`

Comment: @Rahil Wazir  it is loading the whole method. so it has to be retrieved.  anyways i try your suggestion but it not works

Comment: Rahil i edit this i cant do this with your way because i have other methods those give me different result.

Comment: Then you should instead create a private array property `private mydata = array()` and do this `$this->mydata['articles'] = $this->Mdl_Articles->get();` and change your all `$data` variable to `$this->mydata` in index method and pass it to the view `$this->load->view('_main_layout', $this->mydata);`

Comment: mydata also not working.

Comment: Show us the updated code you have tried so far.

Comment: where i can show u? i replace the above code?

Comment: You are doing all fine just make **private** `private $mydata = array();` variable to the scope of class not the method.

Comment: It works. thx bro. Hope u will help me again. where can i accept your answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should instead create a private array property

```
private mydata = array();
```

In your `_homepage` method, contents should be:

```
private function _homepage(){
    // ...
    // target your class scope property
    $this->mydata['articles'] = $this->Mdl_Articles->get();
```

and change your all `$data` variable to `$this->mydata` in `index` method and pass it to the view like this:

```
$this->load->view('_main_layout', $this->mydata);
```